# OSPF DR/BDR question

Tags: cisco, ospf

I have an issue about OSPF. When I try to use "Show ip ospf neighbor" I can not find which router is the DR router or BDR router it always show "Full/-"
Here is my set up

[image]
Can someone help me,
Thank you

Comment: Please post your output as normal text, this is barely readable.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using serial interfaces which use OSPF point-to-point network types as there can only be two devices on a serial link.  DRs are only used on multi-access networks to reduce the number of adjacencies.  They are not used on point-to-point networks, so both routers should be fully adjacent with each other .